# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'

Tags: python, click

i am trying to click on a button with @id=address and get error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'

Any ideas how i can fix it?

```
copy_button = """//*[@id="address"]"""
copy_button.click()
```

Comment: `copy_button` is just a string. What tools are you using? Is this a gui like tk? Are you trying to run a web page with selenium? We need context.

Comment: You missed the step where you find the actual element with that xpath.